# Get dynamical path slug in angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular

How do I Get router path slug in angular 2+

**For example:**
So when I enter to this route: mysite.com/posts/post/15 I want to see in console.log /posts/post/:id

Comment: Take a look at the documentation https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters.

Comment: Do you mean... in a component, you want to get the value 15 from the url?

Comment: @julianobrasil no I want get current url like this: /posts/post/:id

Comment: @Lievno I didn't find it in documentation, if you can please link this case

Comment: @julianobrasil I want string of route where dynamical parameters will be like :id

Comment: Give some use cases (2 or 3 saying exactly what would be the URL and what you expected to see in a console.log).

Comment: /posts/post/:id, /users/user/:id, I want to check route where I am. So when I enter to this route: mysite.com/posts/post/15 I want to see in console.log /posts/post/:id

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular javascript for that (inspect the `window.location` object attributes):

```js
// e.g. url => https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_href

// href is the complete url
const url = window.location.href

// hostname is www.w3schools.com
const hostName = window.location.hostname;

// protocol is https
const protocol = window.location.protocol;

// the "+ 3" at the end is to compensate for "://"
const startIndex = hostname.length + protocol.length + 3;

// prints js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loc_href to console
console.log(href.substring(startIndex));
```

You can get more info about `window.location` object [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution.
I splitted route and check these splitted items on numbers, then replace them with ':id'.
I used this function for checking numbers:

```
hasNumber(myString) {
 return /\d/.test(myString);
}
```